# Value of AP and AR are -1.000 in evaluation

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

As I understand, the AP amd AR calculation are as of follow:

```
Precision = truepositive/ (truepositive + falsepositive)

Recall = truepositive/ (truepositive + falsenegative)
```

Technically, the lowest number they can be is 0, as in total fail in training and 1 as in perfect model. However, with my customer data set, my AP and AR have been consistently `-1.000` when putting through different model for training. What can be the possible reason for this, wouldn't 0 the lowest they can go as I mentioned above?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/6021)? It seems to be related to the labels of your different categories.

Comment: @oxbowerce, thats exactly the issue. My pictures and annotation unique ID started at 1 instead of 0 led to this issue